# Validating JSP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP that has a text box for the user to enter his userId. I have a javascript where I check that the userId is not empty. How can I display the message on the jsp saying "Please enter a userId" . Is there a way to highlight that textbox?

I have seen examples where at the controller an List is created and error messages are added to it.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Simply add a div and concatenating messages on each validation fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all client side validation, really doesn't matter if it's on a JSP, PHP, or raw HTML file. I would suggest looking into some validation libraries. There are certainly plenty available, especially if you are using jQuery.

[Lightweight form validation library in JavaScript ready to include in any web application.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/&ei=M7nBUqDkFai4yAH7pYD4Cw&usg=AFQjCNH8FfGsYulMXOA9bIJwx2tEfwdH7A&sig2=uy9aIRQPlE-ni1sXCW0j1A)

[The Ten Best JavaScript Libraries for Form Validation and Formatting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https://www.codefellows.org/blogs/the-ten-best-javascript-libraries-for-form-validation-and-formatting&ei=M7nBUqDkFai4yAH7pYD4Cw&usg=AFQjCNFuK3FOLm-GkSBjX1ECWxw8tEVHcQ&sig2=rraU1aK_ZNzKCYoeWI2Bhg)

[Parsley.js: Javascript forms validation.Powerful, UX aware & Dead simple.](http://parsleyjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
What I am struggling with is to do somethign very simple.
When the user clicks on the submit button, the javscript validates the various form fields.
How to display the error message? ie- please enter a valid user id .All that I have in my javascript is a function that validates the form fields.

Comment: OK. You can approach this two different ways. You can do a regular post->server validate->redirect back to the page with the message or do some sort of AJAX validation and manipulate the DOM(page elements) with the AJAX response data. For your purposes, the first option is probably sufficient. Submit the form to the server, validate, stick an error message in session, check for the session_error_msg and display it if present.